# Add external library to an action

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm developing an action in IBM-Clound functions, that is called in Watson Assistant dialog.This action has to make a SOAP petition to a WS. The problem is when I try to import the suds library because It is not in the default python libraries. How can I add the library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901638/ibm-cloud-functions-how-to-use-and-upload-own-libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can package Python dependencies by using a virtual environment, virtualenv. The virtual environment allows you to link additional packages that can be installed by using [pip](https://packaging.python.org/installing/), for example.

To install dependencies, package them in a virtual environment, and create a compatible OpenWhisk action:

Create a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) file that contains the pip modules and versions to install.

Install the dependencies and create a virtual environment. The virtual environment directory must be named virtualenv. To ensure compatibility with the OpenWhisk runtime container, package installations inside a virtual environment must use the image that corresponds to the kind.

For kind python:2 use the docker image openwhisk/python2action.

For kind python:3.6 use the docker image ibmfunctions/action-python-v3.6.

For kind python:3.7 use the docker image ibmfunctions/action-python-v3.7.

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/tmp" ibmfunctions/action-python-v3 bash  -c "cd tmp && virtualenv virtualenv && source virtualenv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

Package the virtualenv directory and any additional Python files. The source file that contains the entry point must be named **main**.py.

```
 zip -r helloPython.zip virtualenv __main__.py
```

Create the action helloPython.

```
ibmcloud fn action create helloPython --kind python-jessie:3 helloPython.zip
```

For more details, refer this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#creating-python-actions)